# Is it possible to inherit comments in an abstract method's body from a BaseClass?

Tags: c#, inheritance, comments, resharper, ghostdoc

I have the PersonBaseClass and the EmployeeClass that derives from it.
Now I'd like to define a method body as a comment in the BaseClass that when I use Resharper's "Implement Members" (or manually implement them) it also puts it in the method body.

Something (roughly) like that:

```
public abstract class PersonBaseClass : DependencyObject
{
   //<methodComment>
   // object connectionString;
   // _configurations.TryGetValue("ConnectionString", out connectionString);
   //</methodComment>
   protected abstract void InstanceOnPersonChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs);
}
```

That when implemented will look like that:

```
public class EmployeeClass : PersonBaseClass
{
    protected override void InstanceOnPersonChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        // object connectionString;
        // _configurations.TryGetValue("ConnectionString", out connectionString);
    }
}
```

Is that already possible somehow ? Couldn't get this to work with [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx).

Edit: It would be useful as I want to have the BaseClass in a library and the implementation of it usually looks the same every time.

Comment: Ghost doc is good enough to pull the base class member's comment to overridden member's *comment*. You seem to asking for embedding the comment inside the method. It is unlikely this feature might be available as what you're asking is strange.

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel: and how can I do that ?
I also edited my question above for an explanation for what I'd use this for.

Comment: If "the implementation of it usually looks the same every time", why not make it a virtual method and only change it (i.e. override it), when it's really different? -- Or split the method, so that only the part, that really *is* different, is in an abstract method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly what you're asking, but you can pull the comments using [Ghostdoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) to the inherited members. Note that it will not add the comments to derived class method's body but it will add it in its comment section.

Assume you have a class like this, with comment *Hey, this is great method :)*

```
public abstract class PersonBaseClass
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Hey, this is great method :)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
    /// <param name="eventArgs">The <see cref="EventArgs" /> instance containing the event data.</param>
    protected abstract void InstanceOnPersonChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs);
}
```

Then you add derived class and override the member like this

```
public class EmployeeClass : PersonBaseClass
{
    protected override void InstanceOnPersonChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then place the cursor inside the derived class member's body and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>. It will pull the comments from base class.

And your derived class will look something like this after performing above step.

```
public class EmployeeClass : PersonBaseClass
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Hey, this is great method :)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
    /// <param name="eventArgs">The <see cref="EventArgs" /> instance containing the event data.</param>
    /// <exception cref="System.NotImplementedException"></exception>
    protected override void InstanceOnPersonChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's just what I needed. It's not that important whether or not the comment is inside the method's body.

Comment: Is it possible to somehow indicate that a method has this sort of attached comment or is pressing ctrl + shift + d the only way to find out ?

Comment: @mYnDstrEAm AFAIK there is not. Hunt for it, I was not aware of such thing.